# how to rename many variables in R

Tags: r

I'm really new to coding and R in general. I'm working a df with 77 variable names. I'd like to rename most but not all of them. Here is the code I'm currently using:

```
colnames(df)[colnames(df) == 'oldName'] <- 'newName'
```

But it is really tedious to change one at a time. Is there a way to do it with one block of code?

Comment: Use `%in%` instead of `==`.  If you are using `setnames` from `data.table`, it becomes easy as you can use the specific column to rename

Comment: and look at `?setNames`

Comment: Depends if the names are similar enough that an algorithm expressed as code can rename most/all of them. What are some examples of the names?

Answer (score 1):

`dplyr::rename` is pretty handy for this, e.g.,

```
mtcars %>% dplyr::rename(
  `miles per gallon` = mpg,
  number_gears = gear
)
```